# How to know which controller is called using URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am using routing like this

```
$route['Advertisement/1.0/(:any)']="v1/$1";

$route['Advertisement/1.1/(:any)']="v1_1/$1";
```

eventually both of them just do same work but i have to maintain both of them because of just response is same.

All is i want to know is how do i get to know the which controller is called using URL .If i get to know the URL like so will change the response accordingly so i don't need to maintain two controllers

```
1.0 or 1.1
```

I hope you understand what i am trying to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$this->uri->ruri_string()` to get access to the re-routed URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Codeigniter's [User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/), If you want to know the URL which is hit, then use:

```
$uri_segments = $this->uri->uri_string();
```

To get the [URI segments](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html).

Also, you can use `current_url()`  [URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to get the full URL (including segments); To do that:

```
// Load URL helper first (or use autoload config)
$this->load->helper('url');

// Get the current full URL
$url = current_url();
```

And if you want to get a specific segment of URI, use:

```
// "n" is the segment number you wish to retrieve,
// in this case, n = 2 gets '1.0' or '1.1'
$segment = $this->uri->segment(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your URL looks like this: example.com/Advertisement/1.0/...

```
$this->uri->segment(2);
```

will return 1.0 or 1.1

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you can get the controller name and method name by using the following CI functions

```
$this->router->fetch_class();  // to get controller
$this->router->fetch_method(); // to get method
```

Comment: @rohitarora `How to know that which controller is been called` or `i want to know the url which is hit`? which one is the subject?

Comment: i want to know the url which is hit

Comment: @rohitarora If you `want to know the url which is hit` then use `$this->uri->uri_string()` to get the URI segments, or use `current_url()` helper to get the full URL (including segments)

Comment: @rohitarora Actually "This" answer is not mine, I'll post an answer